# How does Android support multiple storage connections?

Tags: usb, android, storage

I'm unsure if this is happening at the software level rather than the hardware level, but since I'm looking into this technology to bake it into a hardware solution, I've decided to ask it here first.

So, an average Android device has internal storage. With this storage you can do things like save pictures, movies, and documents. Yet, it allows you to plug in a USB connection to access said storage, therefore having two R/Ws for one storage bus. How is this possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about operating system usage, and additionally is based on an erroneous premise - Android does not permit simultaneous USB Mass Storage and internal access to a traditional storage media, while the later MTP  implementation is not a USB Mass storage file system but rather a USB file transfer scheme.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Part of me asking this was to amend my premise. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In exactly the same way any operating system deals with multiple read/write requests from multiple sources... scheduler.

The underlying operating system of Android is Linux. This really belongs on superuser.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1631894

> **I/O SCHEDULERS**
>
> Q. "What purposes does an i/o scheduler serve?" A. Minimize hard disk
>   seek latency. Prioritize I/O requests from processes. Allocate disk
>   bandwidth for running processes. Guarantee that certain requests will
>   be served before a deadline.
>
> So in the simplest of simplest form: Kernel controls the disk access
>   using I/O Scheduler.
>
> Q. "What goals every I/O scheduler tries to balance?" A. Fairness (let
>   every process have its share of the access to disk) Performance (try
>   to serve requests close to current disk head position first, because
>   seeking there is fastest) Real-time (guarantee that a request is
>   serviced in a given time)
>
> Q. "Description, advantages, disadvantages of each I/O Scheduler?" A.
>
> **1) Noop**
>
> Inserts all the incoming I/O requests to a First In First Out queue
>   and implements request merging. Best used with storage devices that
>   does not depend on mechanical movement to access data (yes, like our
>   flash drives). Advantage here is that flash drives does not require
>   reordering of multiple I/O requests unlike in normal hard drives.
>
> Advantages: Serves I/O requests with least number of cpu cycles.
>   (Battery friendly?) Best for flash drives since there is no seeking
>   penalty. Good throughput on db systems. Disadvantages: Reduction in
>   number of cpu cycles used is proportional to drop in performance.
>
> **2) Deadline**
>
> Goal is to minimize I/O latency or starvation of a request. The same
>   is achieved by round robin policy to be fair among multiple I/O
>   requests. Five queues are aggressively used to reorder incoming
>   requests.
>
> Advantages: Nearly a real time scheduler. Excels in reducing latency
>   of any given single I/O. Best scheduler for database access and
>   queries. Bandwidth requirement of a process - what percentage of CPU
>   it needs, is easily calculated. Like noop, a good scheduler for solid
>   state/flash drives. Disadvantages: When system is overloaded, set of
>   processes that may miss deadline is largely unpredictable.
>
> **3) CFQ**
>
> Completely Fair Queuing scheduler maintains a scalable per-process I/O
>   queue and attempts to distribute the available I/O bandwidth equally
>   among all I/O requests. Each per-process queue contains synchronous
>   requests from processes. Time slice allocated for each queue depends
>   on the priority of the 'parent' process. V2 of CFQ has some fixes
>   which solves process' i/o starvation and some small backward seeks in
>   the hope of improving responsiveness.
>
> Advantages: Considered to deliver a balanced i/o performance. Easiest
>   to tune. Excels on multiprocessor systems. Best database system
>   performance after deadline. Disadvantages: Some users report media
>   scanning takes longest to complete using CFQ. This could be because of
>   the property that since the bandwidth is equally distributed to all
>   i/o operations during boot-up, media scanning is not given any special
>   priority. Jitter (worst-case-delay) exhibited can sometimes be high,
>   because of the number of tasks competing for the disk.
>
> **4) BFQ**
>
> Instead of time slices allocation by CFQ, BFQ assigns budgets. Disk is
>   granted to an active process until it's budget (number of sectors)
>   expires. BFQ assigns high budgets to non-read tasks. Budget assigned
>   to a process varies over time as a function of it's behavior.
>
> Advantages: Believed to be very good for usb data transfer rate.
>   Believed to be the best scheduler for HD video recording and video
>   streaming. (because of less jitter as compared to CFQ and others)
>   Considered an accurate i/o scheduler. Achieves about 30% more
>   throughput than CFQ on most workloads. Disadvantages: Not the best
>   scheduler for benchmarking. Higher budget assigned to a process can
>   affect interactivity and increased latency.
>
> **5) SIO**
>
> Simple I/O scheduler aims to keep minimum overhead to achieve low
>   latency to serve I/O requests. No priority quesues concepts, but only
>   basic merging. Sio is a mix between noop & deadline. No reordering or
>   sorting of requests.
>
> Advantages: Simple, so reliable. Minimized starvation of requests.
>   Disadvantages: Slow random-read speeds on flash drives, compared to
>   other schedulers. Sequential-read speeds on flash drives also not so
>   good.
>
> **6) V(R)**
>
> Unlike other schedulers, synchronous and asynchronous requests are not
>   treated separately, instead a deadline is imposed for fairness. The
>   next request to be served is based on it's distance from last request.
>
> Advantages: May be best for benchmarking because at the peak of it's
>   'form' VR performs best. Disadvantages: Performance fluctuation
>   results in below-average performance at times. Least reliable/most
>   unstable.

Comment: I didn't realize it was happening on the software side. Thank you.

Comment: No, the scheduler really has nothing particularly to do with it.  The question is based on a false premise - the Android versions that use a storage scheme were shared access would be problematic don't permit shared access but rather explicitly switch it between the phone and the USB host, while the later version that do permit it use a fundamentally different storage scheme.

Comment: Actually it is. Android has for quite some time shipped with a number of IO schedulers: BFQ, CFQ, Deadline, Noop, SIO

Comment: No, you are only digging a hole deeper into irrelevance.  The issue has nothing to do with I/O scheduling, and everything to do with **consistency**.  But as already mentioned, there's no magic here - the puzzle proposed by the question is proposed from misunderstanding.  In the designs where this would be difficult, it is simply not permitted at all.